# Is there a way to delay upload request in Cypress?

Tags: upload, cypress

I am writing 'multiple upload' tests in Cypress and my case would be to start multiple uploads and then cancel the first of them and let other file uploads finish.
Currently, the upload goes too fast and the test can't manage to cancel the first request in time.
My question would be - is there a way to delay or stater the request so that the test can have time to cancel an upload?
I already tried cy.network({ mode: 'SLOW3G' }) with no success.
I tried Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol' with no success.
And cy.intercept with delay but with no success because if I use response setup it always comes back with error 500.
I would try to avoid using big files to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the delay in the response https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Modifying-an-incoming-response where you aren't stubbing the response but adding to it. Or, you could try throttling, which is mentioned in the same link.

Comment: Yes, by I get error 500 in that case.

Comment: Anyway, at the end I did similar, as my rest API was express, I added slow down via express.